# Win11 custom taskbar control

Tags: windows, shell, winapi, taskbar

Currently I need to display a textbox on the Windows 11 taskbar but sadly Deskbands are now deprecated, however I found a program called Performance Counter that does something like below

[image]

now I want to know how this is done? This works for Windows 11 however from what I know is that there is no official API to implement a custom taskbar control

Comment: According to this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/discussions/2320 - the only method they know-of that works is to manipulate hWnds of the Taskbar's child windows directly, including resizing and moving them around - _erk_

Comment: `TrafficMonitor` is a Win32 C++ program that targets the Windows 11 Taskbar with hacks like that, it's pretty gnarly: https://github.com/zhongyang219/TrafficMonitor/blob/master/TrafficMonitor/TaskBarDlgDrawCommon.h

Comment: @Dai I've tried that and checked the Win11 taskbar with spy++ and seems like it's only 2 windows, one for the icons and one for the entire taskbar with the icons window toggleable, sadly, I need to position my custom control right next to the search bar and this might not be enough information to just get the position and rectangles of 2 windows

Comment: Deskbands still work in Windows 10, but not in Windows 11 (unless you install some hack tool such as https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher which reverts 11 taskbar to 10 taskbar). This "Performance Counter" you mention seems to render exectly like TrafficMonitor it's probably using the same hacks (or it's a full rebrand...). Search for GetShellTrayWndHandleAndSaveWindows11TaskBarExistenceInfoToTheApp in the source and around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize @Dai and @Simon Mourier 's comments.

[Desk bands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#deskbands) are not supported as of Windows 7. The applications being working are to hack the taskbar such as https://github.com/zhongyang219/TrafficMonitor mentioned in the comments.

You may [send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332) for a reliable formal example.